# "Reply-to Address" Email

Tags: email

I searched the web for last couple of days for "Reply-to Address" in the email but had no luck so, here I am.

In my wordpress site, there are multiple store owners who can sell their products.
When visitors buy a certain item (listed by different owners), that particular owner gets an email notification (Note that it is mandatory to put the visitor's email address during checkout process)

However the email is from "Admin" email account.

I searched for how to set up "reply-to" address so the owners can reply directly to the customer's email address instead of admin account.

Here is an example that I saw which I am trying to achieve:

[image]

In this image, the site is `abc.ca` and the `customer@gmail.com` bought something. Then the `owner@gmail.com` got the email, which the owner can now send a reply back to the customer directly from the email.

How can I achieve something like this?

### EDIT:

Here is the code that I have now:

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_email_headers', 'my_from_reply');
 function my_from_reply() {
 return 'From: my@email.here' . "\r\n";
 }
```

And this is the customer's billing email.

```
 <?php echo $order->billing_email; ?>
```

How can I modify the first one to include the "billing_email" instead of "my@email.here"

Thank you

Comment: Are you using some particular e-commerce solution?

Comment: yes. I am using woocommerce for that. =)

Comment: Without you showing the code that send the email it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Well, there is no code. I could not even start on it, or don't even know where to even start from.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If and when you are using [`wp_mail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail), then you can just set `Reply-To` for the `$headers` parameter. Exemplary usage below:

```
$to          = "abc@def.gh";
$subject     = "Using Reply-To with wp_mail";
$message     = "This is an example for using Reply-To with wp_mail.";
$headers[]   = 'Reply-To: Name Name <ijk@lmn.op>';
$attachments = array();
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
```

There is a hook [`wp_mail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail) hook too, which you could use to change the parameters.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken WC uses `wp_mail()` and has a hook `woocommerce_email_headers` you can use.

Comment: So, I edited my original post to include the changes which needs some modification. Any suggestions to how I can edit it so that "billing_email" is can be returned.

Comment: So I tried some modification, but no luck. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have never really done this with WC, I just remembered, there are some possibilities. So I can't give you immediate and concrete help. @steveKim

Comment: please note, the `$headers` array example in this answer is INCORRECT. It should be `$headers = array('Reply-To: Name Name <ijk@lmn.op>');` It does NOT take an associative array.

Comment: @JaredHenderson Thanks, you're right! I prefer it like this though: `$headers[] = 'Reply-To: Name Name <ijk@lmn.op>';`

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php

```
// Function changes email that your site sending from
function change_my_from_address( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'example@example.pl';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'change_my_from_address' );

// Change sender name
function change_my_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'example.pl';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'change_my_sender_name' );
```